# How to add for example 30 or 60 minutes into a specific time

Tags: php, mysql

I have an input where you can select a time between 00:00 - 24:00 (displayed in "utleid" and 2 radio buttons where you can choose 30 minutes or 60 minutes.

I want the input where you can write your own time and + it with either 30 or 60 minutes depending on what they choose

so lets for example say i choose "30" and type in 12:00 i want it to insert into the "inntid" "12:30".

I tried doing something but it didnt work :P

DATABASE:
[image: DATABASE]

HTML:

```
<div class="tid">
<label class="container"><span class="tidtekst">30m</span>
  <input type="radio" class="checked" name="tid" id="tid" value="30">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="container"><span class="tidtekst">60m</span>
  <input type="radio" name="tid" value="60">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<input type="text" name="tid_custom" id="egentid" placeholder="Tid">
</div>
```

```
<h2 class="overskrift">Tiden klokka starter:</h2>
  <input type="time" id="utleidnar" name="utleidnar"
       min="00:00" max="24:00" required>
```

PHP:

```
$velgut = "SELECT utleid FROM utleie";
$velgtid = "SELECT tid FROM utleie";
$inntid = "INSERT INTO utleie (inntid) VALUES ('$velgut + $velginn')";

if (@$_POST["submit"] != "") {
    $baatnr = @$_POST["baatnr"];
    $fornavn = @$_POST["fornavn"];
    $etternavn = @$_POST["etternavn"];
    $tid = @$_POST["tid"];

    if ($tid == null) {
        $tid = @$_POST["tid_custom"];
    }

    $kr = @$_POST["kr"];

    if ($kr == null) {
        $kr = @$_POST["kr_custom"];
    }

    $utleidnar = @$_POST["utleidnar"];
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO utleie (utleid, inntid, baatnr, fornavn, etternavn, tid, kr)
VALUES ('$utleidnar', '', '$baatnr', '$fornavn', '$etternavn', '$tid', '$kr')";
```

Comment: `I tried doing something but it didnt work` - what did you try?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php

Comment: you're open to SQL injection and you're use of `@` IMO is redundant

Comment: @RamRaider     $inntid = "INSERT INTO utleie (inntid) VALUES ('$velgut + $velginn')";

Comment: `$velginn` isn't even defined in the above code as far as I can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to parse the value in php. Try something like this:

```
$timestamp = strtotime('12:00') + 30*60;
$time = date('H:i', $timestamp);
```

Comment: maybe not `30*60` (1800)

Comment: Thank you! :)  !

Answer (score 1):

Use the PHP builtin `datetime` function to calculate the additional 30 or 60 minutes.

```
$utleidnar = '13:00';
$tid = 60;

$stime = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i',$utleidnar);
$stime->add(new DateInterval('PT' . $tid . 'M'));
$inntid = $stime->format('H:i');
echo $inntid;  // this has the new value you want
```

Results in:

> 14:00

Answer (score 0):

can't you use mtkime?

```
$explodedTime = explode(':',$utleidnar);
$tid = abs($_POST['tid']);
$time = date('H:i', mktime($explodedTime[0],$explodedTime[1] + $tid,0));
```